# Laravel authentication always fails with Auth::attempt(), even with correct user input

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm new to laravel and I'm having problems with authentication. I was able to create users from a form and they are registered in the database. But every time I try to connect :
`Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' =>$password]` returns `false` . When I use `Auth::getLastAttempted()` I can see the user information in the authentication failed. I've followed all the procedures in the documentation, but authentication still fails. Here are the different parts of my code :

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class UtilisateurController extends Controller
{
    public function connexion(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
         
          $email =$request->input('email');
          $password = $request->input('password');
             
         if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' =>$password])) { 
             dd("Ok");
           }
            else {
              dd("No");
             }

        } elseif ($request->isMethod('get')) {
            return view('connexion');
        }
    }

    public function inscription(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
           
           $name = $request->input('nom_complet');
           $email = $request->input('email');
           $contact = $request->input('contact');
           $password = $request->input('password');

           $utilisateur = new User();
           $utilisateur->nom_complet = $name;
           $utilisateur->email = $email;
           $utilisateur->contact = $contact;
           $utilisateur->password = Hash::make($password);
           $utilisateur->photo = "Default.png";
           $utilisateur->solde = 0;
           $utilisateur->statut_u = true;
           $utilisateur->save();

           return redirect('/Connexion');

        } elseif ($request->isMethod('get')) {
            return view('inscription');
        }

    }
}
```

**User model**

```
namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nom_complet',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**Login page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>connexion</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>connexion</h2>

    <form action="/Connexion" method="post">
        @csrf 
        <label for="email">E-mail :</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br>
        <label for="password">Password :</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br>
        <input type="submit" value="connexion">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Routes**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\UtilisateurController;

Route::get('/Connexion', [UtilisateurController::class, 'connexion']);
Route::post('/Connexion', [UtilisateurController::class, 'connexion']);
```

I tried changing the hash to bcrypt, but nothing changed. I even shouted several users, but I couldn't connect with any of them.

Comment: show how you are creating these user records

Comment: Hi lagbox, I just added this

Comment: Debug your code; apparently in Laravel `10.x`, if you do `$user = new User()`, then `$user->password = 'test'`, then finally `$user->password`, it outputs the hashed password, and not `test`. So if you're doing `$user->password = Hash::make('test')`, you are indeed "double-hashing" your password. I was alarmed at the answer below, since it says "DO NOT HASH YOUR PASSWORD", which in most cases is insane advice, but not if hashing is already being done. Try removing `Hash::make()` from your code and see if the password is still hashed in the database. https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYkwF.png

Comment: @TimLewis the Laravel documentation doesn't mention this, and includes [an example](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/hashing#hashing-passwords) of setting a user password with an explicit hash. I'm doing a manual hash on my app as well... (not doubting your screenshot, just curious where this is being done. Maybe a mutator that's smart enough to not double hash things?)

Comment: @miken32 I know right? The only mention I could find for auto-hashing was this: *"If you are using one of the Laravel application starter kits, Bcrypt will be used for registration and authentication by default."*. The local project I tested this code with indeed is using Breeze, but yeah, my experience is the same as yours; I've always done manual hashing (and I actually am in this project, but it's using `User::create()` instead of `User::make()` or `new User() ... $user->save()`). Hence the alarm when reading the answer below, but it lines up  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvOKE.png)

Comment: @TimLewis looks like this is done in the default `User` model provided by Laravel's sample app: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/app/Models/User.php#L43

Comment: @miken32 Ah good find! I figured it would be an Accessor, like `public function password(): Attribute { return Attribute::make(set: ...); }`; didn't know there was a `casts` option for this. I do notice it's missing from the code included in this question though... So maybe it's not the issue OP is facing at all? Hard to say lol.

Comment: Hi @TimLewis , you're right! It works! No more need to apply bcrypt manually for the password.

Answer (score 0):

so i do not see the register controller but I assume you are hashing your password there. DO NOT! I had the same problem and when I removed the hashing when creating the user it all worked - turns out Laravel is automatically hashing it so when you do it as well you double do it.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::make($request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'age' => 'required|integer|min:18',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8|regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]+$/|confirmed',
        ]));

        $user->save();

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect()->intended('/');
    }
}
```

This code produces such password `$2y$10$ClmEfFuH6Sly/h.kDndEDekRhJ3KhN.RUQQsw5t9cWpS1DAoswThW`

Hope it works for you!

Comment: The only way automatic hashing is done is with a specific cast on the `User` model. This isn't the case according to the code provided by OP. See here for an example: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/app/Models/User.php#L43

Comment: Oh I see, I might have configured mine for auto hashing and forgot about it